# How to animate UIBarbutton item programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, ios10

I need to animate  left bar button moving to right side of menu list view in slide bar menu view controller
How can i animate this in swift3.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { (Void) 

        }, completion:nil)
```

Comment: "I need to animate left bar button item for creating sidebar menu in swift." Can you specify type of animation?

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer:

You can use a `Cloaking` in your code

1.create a `BarButton` on the `window` the appearance is the same as your `left bar button` on your `viewController`, and hide the `left bar button` on your `viewController`.

2.animate the `BarButton` which on the `window` to your ' right side of menu list view in slide bar menu view controller'.

3.on your  `slide bar menu view controller` create a `BarButton` the same as your `barButton`, and remove the `BarButton` which on the `window`.

so it will realize your idea.